# Do you know any cluster /dev/shm like interface or RAM based, cluster filesystem?

Tags: cache, cluster

I am looking for some sort of clustered /dev/shm like device or RAM based, clustered filesystem, running on Linux, so it supports mirroring.
Or there is anything stable enough which would do the job the same way? So I can replicate RAM based data? I would like to have it self-repairing (e.g. just restart recovers the service).

Comment: What's your usage scenario?

Comment: It is meant to be universal in this case to support any usage scenario with RAID-1 ramdisk, using synchronous and asynchronous I/O.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could theoretically run [drbd](http://www.drbd.org/) with the underlying devices being files on a [tmpfs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmpfs#Linux) filesystem. Whatever you're doing sounds a bit crazy though...

Comment: I just need cluster storage with no flushing to disk, because it runs tiny os with tiny I/O

Comment: Oh thank you very much, this is precisely what I was looking for :-))))) Yes it is crazy as hell. AND drbd is actually all done the way I was thinking of.

Comment: you can try with glusterfs, gluster volume create gvola gnode1:/dev/shm gnode2:/dev/shm